# Banach Circle Fractal: Find factor scale $s$ such that between small circle is not overlap in $n$-th step as $n\to\infty$

Tags: solution-verification, fractals

[image]
Source: [from stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jwgD.png)

I want to draw a Banach Fractal as picture above.

- First step, draw a circle with radius $r$.
- Second step, draw 9 smaller circles with radius $s\cdot r$ ($s$ is
  factor scale, $0<s<1$) [one circle in center and 8 circles in circle
  side].
- Third step, each 9 smaller circle from second step, is drawn by 9
  smaller circles with radius $s^2\cdot r$ [one circle in center and 8 circles in circle
  side].
- etc.

In picture above, from third step the smaller circle is overlap. Now, I want to calculate the factor scale $s$ such that the smaller circle is not overlap in $n$-th step as $n\to\infty$.

I try to calculate as follows.

For first step until infinity step, total radius of smaller circle is
$$sr+s^2 r+s^3 r+\ldots = \dfrac{sr}{1-s}.$$

So, for first step until infinity step total diameter of smaller circle is
$$T_d=2\dfrac{sr}{1-s}.$$

The circumference of first step circle is $2\pi r$.

Because of we draw 8 circles in first step circle side, now I divide circumference by 8.

So, total diameter per small circle in "first circle side" is

$$T_d=\dfrac{2\pi r}{8}=\dfrac{\pi r}{4}$$

Now, we have equality
$$2\dfrac{sr}{1-s}=\dfrac{\pi r}{4}.$$

Solving the equality:
\begin{align}
&2\dfrac{sr}{1-s}=\dfrac{\pi r}{4}\\
\iff &\dfrac{s}{1-s}=\dfrac{\pi }{8}\\
\iff &8s=\pi-\pi s\\
\iff &(8+\pi) s=\pi \\
\iff & \dfrac{\pi}{8+\pi}.
\end{align}

Now I have the factor scale $s=\dfrac{\pi}{8+\pi}$ such that between small circle is not overlap in $n$-th step as $n\to\infty$.

Is it correct answer?

I think it over a hour and I'm not sure with my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could just draw it and see:

[image]

Close, but not quite.  The correct value of

$$
s = \frac{\sin(\pi/8)}{\sin(\pi/8) + \sin(5\pi/8)} = \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{2}}
$$

should yield the so-called [octa-gasket](https://observablehq.com/@mcmcclur/poly-gaskets):

[image]

You can see why this should work once you see how the following lines perfectly partition the pieces:

[image]

Once you get to that point, finding $s$ is a simple application of trigonometry.

You can find the code for the pictures [on Observable](https://observablehq.com/@mcmcclur/circular-octa-gasket).